# How to join two supplier results

Tags: sql

I have selected and used sum() over PARTITION for the sales data every month by branch. I have tried group by but then I could not get the branch total sales.

And I want to specifically see the results of two suppliers and their value in percentage to total sales.

```
SELECT 

distinct sv.Branch 'Branch',
dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY 'Exclusive Tag',
sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.branch, dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY) 'Supplier 1',
sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.branch, dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY) 'Supplier 2',
sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.Branch) 'Branch Overall',
sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.branch, dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY)/sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.Branch) 'Amount %'
FROM dbo.SalesView as sv
WHERE sv.Time between ? and ?
```

But the output is putting the results on separate lines.

```
|Branch|Exclusive Tag|Supplier 1|Supplier 2|Branch Overall|Amount %|
|000001|EXCLSUPPLIER1|700       |700       |25000         |2.8%    |
|000001|EXCLSUPPLIER2|1400      |1400      |25000         |5.6%    |
|000002|EXCLSUPPLIER1|1300      |1300      |60000         |2.2%    |
|000002|EXCLSUPPLIER2|800       |800       |60000         |1.3%    |
```

I want the results to be something like this

```
|Branch|Supplier 1|Supplier 2|Branch Overall|Supp1 %|Supp2 %|
|000001|700       |1400      |25000         |2.8%   |5.6%   |
|000002|1300      |800       |60000         |2.2%   |1.3%   |
```

Please let me know what changes I can make to the codes to show the desired results. Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server? If so - which version?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best solution and it is not the final one, but I have not enough information - for example I don't know how do you join to dim table. I guess you should use PIVOT. Here goes some dirtier solution:

```
SELECT sv.Branch [Branch]
--,dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY [Exclusive Tag]
,(SELECT SUM(svint.Revenue) FROM dbo.SalesView svint WHERE svint.Branch=sv.Branch AND dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY='EXCLSUPPLIER1') [Supplier 1]
,(SELECT SUM(svint.Revenue) FROM dbo.SalesView svint WHERE svint.Branch=sv.Branch AND dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY='EXCLSUPPLIER2') [Supplier 2]
,SUM(sv.Revenue) [Branch Overall]
,(SELECT SUM(svint.Revenue) FROM dbo.SalesView svint WHERE svint.Branch=sv.Branch AND dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY='EXCLSUPPLIER1')/SUM(sv.Revenue) [Supp1]
,(SELECT SUM(svint.Revenue) FROM dbo.SalesView svint WHERE svint.Branch=sv.Branch AND dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY='EXCLSUPPLIER2')/SUM(sv.Revenue) [Supp2]
--sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.branch, dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY) 'Supplier 1',
--sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.branch, dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY) 'Supplier 2',
--sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.Branch) 'Branch Overall',
--sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.branch, dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY)/sum(sv.Revenue) over (PARTITION by sv.Branch) 'Amount %'
FROM dbo.SalesView as sv
WHERE sv.Time between ? and ?
GROUP BY sv.Branch
```

Comment: full join DIM_product as dim on dim.Product_KEY = sv.Product

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`:

```
SELECT sv.Branch,
       sum(case when dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY = 'EXCLSUPPLIER1' then sv.Revenue else 0 end) as Supplier1,
       sum(case when dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY = 'EXCLSUPPLIER2' then sv.Revenue else 0 end) as Supplier2,
       sum(sv.Revenue) as Branch,
       sum(case when dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY = 'EXCLSUPPLIER1' then sv.Revenue else 0 end) / sum(sv.Revenue) as Supplier1_ratio,
       sum(case when dim.ExclusiveGroup_KEY = 'EXCLSUPPLIER2' then sv.Revenue else 0 end) / sum(sv.Revenue) as Supplier2_ratio
FROM dbo.SalesView as sv
WHERE sv.Time between ? and ?
GROUP BY sv.Branch;
```

Your problem is a problem of pivoting or conditional aggregation.  I'm not sure why you would approach this using `select distinct` and window functions.

Comment: yes, Pivoting works for my problem. And your codes work perfectly according to my needs. Thanks a lot mate. I will do some research on pivoting in sql now :)